Made-for-TV movie about a man who gets better by taking Vitamin C
There was a TV movie in the early 80s about a man who cured his sickness by taking Vitamin C.  I was very young the time it aired so that is the gist of my recollection. 
It would have been broadcast on one of the 3 major networks at the time (ABC, NBC, CBS) though I'm pretty sure it was CBS.

Is there any other detail about the movie that you can think of?  For example, how was he sick?  How did he ingest the vitamin c?  Details can help answer this question.

He was an older guy and got the treatment intravenously; looks like smooshie got the answer.

How about Anatomy of an Illness by and about Norman Cousins?
From the Wiki article about Norman Cousins

Cousins also served as Adjunct Professor of Medical Humanities for the
  School of Medicine at the University of California, Los Angeles, where
  he did research on the biochemistry of human emotions, which he long
  believed were the key to human beings’ success in fighting illness. It
  was a belief he maintained even as he battled heart disease, which he
  fought both by taking massive doses of Vitamin C and, according to
  him, by training himself to laugh.[4][5] He wrote a collection of
  best-selling non-fiction books on illness and healing, as well as a
  1980 autobiographical memoir, Human Options: An Autobiographical
  Notebook. Late in life Cousins was diagnosed with a form of arthritis
  then called Marie-Strumpell's disease (ankylosing spondylitis),[6]
  although this diagnosis is currently in doubt and it has been
  suggested that Cousins may actually have had reactive arthritis. His
  struggle with this illness is detailed in the book and movie Anatomy
  of an Illness.


Hmm, sounds more like a bio for Linus Pauling.

I found some clips of the movie on YouTube.  That's got to be it...I mean, how many early 80s TV movies could have been about a guy curing an ailment on Vitamin C?  It's incredible you were able to find that on such little detail
, smooshie.
